# Can 1 or 2 of the three of a kind cards be a clone card?

Tags: exploding-kittens, zombie-kittens

In three of a kind rule, can I play for example 1 cat card and 2 clone cards to make a three of a kind card ?
or 2 nope cards and a clone card to make a three of a kind card and so on ...
so the ultimate question is : can clone card be used in two of a kind and three of a kind combos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this works, there's a little explainer [in the rules](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0345/9180/1483/files/APznzaYRUJvHZxreBC36pvUt2bPsnpwzndR-l4z3p11HXXfza7N0eb3nuZv2v9VAzktzZBSvoIoiLFNqBrMVFbx4xLmLaKj5iUI_xBJ7Fbnv4Z-lTkjlU8V2yCmJVRV5GE8boXfnYZOowHlGjXEfmPRRaIStH-o5VwtAqHmasdQZ5o7ieLBDb54.pdf) for the Zombie expansion underneath the base clone instructions (emphasis mine):

> **You can play a Cat Card with a Clone to create a pair** and steal
> a card (because the Clone becomes the same card as the Cat
> Card you put beneath it). This only works if you are the player who
> played both the Cat Card AND the Clone―you could not play a
> Clone on top of a Cat Card played by another player!

The game doesn't specifically mention the 3 of a kind triplet combo, just the two of a kind pair combo, but since they both work in the same way, just with more cards played together, it's probably safe to assume the 3 of a kind combo works the same way.

Comment: I assumed the same.Thanks for your reply. So 1 cat card and 2 clone cards CAN make a three of a kind  interesting.